# Write a semi-compact FizzBuzz that can scale handle to "unlimited" if cases

Tags: code-challenge, c#

I saw **Tom Scott's** video on **FizzBuzz** *https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QPZ0pIK_wsc*
so I felt to write my own more "complex" version,this is what I came up with, its very flexibly and easy to scale, and its easy to add more if cases that can trigger functions.

**"The challenge":** Write a semi-compact "complex FizzBuzz" that can scale handle to "unlimited" if cases, ex. if multiple of 3 do A if multiple of 5 do B of multiple of 3 and 5 do C, if multiple of 3,5,7 and 11 do D  etc.

**Code(C# console application):**

```
// FizzBuzz
// Patrik Fröher
// 2017-07-31
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace fizzBuzz
{
    class Program
    {
        static string isM(int i, int m)
        {
            if (i % m == 0) { return ("1"); }
            return "0";
        }

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            List<string> tmp = new List<string>();
            bool loop = true;
            int i = 1;
            string m3;
            string s3 = "Fizz";
            string m5;
            string s5 = "Buzz";
            string m7;
            string s7 = "Fuzz";
            string m11;
            string s11 = "Biff";
            string m13;
            string s13 = "Buff";
            string mm;

            while (loop)
            {
                m3 = isM(i, 3);
                m5 = isM(i, 5);
                m7 = isM(i, 7);
                m11 = isM(i, 11);
                m13 = isM(i, 13);
                mm = (m3 + m5 + m7 + m11 + m13);

                switch (mm)
                {
                    case "00000": tmp.Add(i.ToString()); break;
                    case "10000": tmp.Add(s3); break;
                    case "01000": tmp.Add(s5); break;
                    case "11000": tmp.Add(s3 + s5); break;
                    case "00100": tmp.Add(s7); break;
                    case "00010": tmp.Add(s11); break;
                    case "00110": tmp.Add(s7 + s11); break;
                    case "00001": tmp.Add(s13); break;
                    case "11111": tmp.Add("Patan77.com"); loop = false; break;
                }
                i++;
            }
            Console.SetBufferSize(Console.BufferWidth, (tmp.Count + 1));
            tmp.ForEach(Console.WriteLine);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Hiya! Questions on this site are usually a challenge - this reads like an answer. If you would like someone to look over your code, you might try [CodeReview](https://codereview.stackexchange.com).

Comment: well I just posted my solution to the "complex FizzBuzz" challenge,  with the hope that others might post theirs solutions to "complex FizzBuzz"

Comment: Try specifying a win condition and clarifying that the posted code is a sample. I'm assuming you want shortest code to win? Also, what do you mean by "handling unlimited if cases"? Is there a specific set of cases for us to test, or should we specify where to expand on conditions in our answer, and can we just have no cases but say it can be expanded on?

Comment: @PatrikFröhler In your example you only ever append a string, is your hope for this to be able to do other tasks?  Like if it's divisible by 10, print its value mod 4, or something in this same vein?

Comment: Here is one way: `#include<map>
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;using rmap=map<int,string,greater<int>>;int main(int c,char*v[]){rmap r;string y;int i,f,x,n=c<2?100:atoi(v[1]);while(cin>>x>>y)r.insert(make_pair(x,y));for(i=1;f=0,i<n;i++){for(rmap::value_type&z:r)if(0==i%z.first){f=1;cout<<z.second<<endl;break;}!f&&cout<<i<<endl;}}`
When you run it you supply the rules in order of importance on stdin so for fizzbuzz you would give it `3 fizz 5 buzz 15 fizzbuzz`.  It isn't particularly golfed well but I can't make an answer anyway so it doesn't matter.